# Clean All build directories in Azure DevOps Pipeline settings is not working while using YAML configuration

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I use Azure DevOps for some time, and I always use Classic Editor GUI when crafting Build Pipeline. Now I'm trying to create new pipeline using YAML. Everything went well and the build was successful. But, I have noticed different behavior in checkout task compared to pipeline using Classic Editor. In both pipelines, settings used in 'Get sources' tab are same(see the below screenshot)

[image]

In case of Classic Editor pipeline, checkout task Deletes and recreates `$(Agent.BuildDirectory).` This results in initializing a new, local Git repository for every build. But, for YAML pipeline, checkout task only performing a `git clean -ffdx` and removing source directories only. How to resolve this issue for YAML pipelines?

YAML pipeline log:

[image]

Classic Editor pipeline log:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting clean all build directories option(in below screenshot) in devops UI is not working in case of YAML builds.

[image]

But you can specify this in YAML file itself by using the workspace setting of a Job. This is working as expected.

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  workspace:
    clean: all # what to clean up before the job runs - outputs | resources | all
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

It is really strange because I have this (in YAML build)

[image]

I found this in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#get-the-source-code):

> When clean is set to true the build pipeline performs an undo of any changes in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. More specifically, the following Git commands are executed prior to fetching the source.

```
git clean -ffdx
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Do you have clean option enabled?

Comment: What should be the issue? Where should I need to check.. in the YAML file or Pipeline settings... do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have no idea. I just created a pipeline to check it. I didn't do anything special to get this. Can you create a new pipeline and check this? How old is your organisation?

Comment: Yes. I have checked with a new pipeline. For the first run, I'm getting this logs and git initialisation is happening. But from second run, checkout task only performing a git clean -ffdx only. Means, for every build it's not initialising a new local repo. This is the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

It will work ONLY if you will add this task to the YAML file where your pipeline is defined:

```
- task: PostBuildCleanup@3
```

If this task is added and Clean is set to false inside 'Get sources' tab -> it will delete $(Agent.BuildDirectory) ( not just sourcesc directory which is ussualy "s" dir, but the artifacts "a" dir and binary "b" dir as well )

From  'Get sources' tab you can fine tune what to delete by setting Clean option to "true" and choosing between available options ( sources dir, sources dir and binary dir, all directories ... )

If your build uses a Git repository, a minimal portion of the .git folder will remain on disk. Those remaining files are needed by the build agent's built-in Post Job Cleanup.